# Why eval fails here?

Tags: javascript, eval

```
0001: response
$[0] = [string] "{\"code\":200,\"id\":121}"
0001: eval(response)
SyntaxError: invalid label
```

Anyone knows?

Comment: Your shell is confusing everyone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to wrap it in `()` to trigger expression evaluation, like this:

```
eval("(" + response + ")")
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yEFzZ/).

---

Though a better method is native JSON handling:

```
var result = JSON.parse(response);
```

Just include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) for older browser (< IE8) support, the call is the same...it just adds the global `JSON` object if it's missing.

Comment: Oh heck yeah!  You saved my butt!!  This was exactly what I was looking for..  :)

Comment: Thanks mate, eval worked but somehow JSON.parse failed

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the JSON string in parentheses.

Otherwise, the `{ ... }` is interpreted as a block of executable statements, which it isn't.

By surrounding it in parentheses, you force the interpreter to interpret it as an expression.