# eval(...) won't work on objects that contain functions

Tags: javascript, eval, strict

`eval`ing a string that declares an array with functions works fine. However, `eval`ing a string that declares an object with functions does not work. Can anyone tell me why?

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKLss/) and the following code demonstrate the problem:

```
"use strict";

// functions in arrays are ok:
var x = "[ function() {}, [function() {}] ]";
var o = eval(x);
console.log(o[1]);

// functions in objects are not ok (for some reason):
var y = "{a: function() {}, b: [function() {}] }";
var o = eval(y);
console.log(o['a']);
```

Only the second `eval` causes trouble.

In Chrome, I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function.

In IE 11, I get:

> Expected identifier

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943278/javascript-eval-expression , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305003/why-eval-fails-here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791202/javascript-eval-return-behavior?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360356/why-the-open-quote-and-bracket-for-eval-jsonstring-when-parsing-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't where you think it is.

Change

```
var y = "{a: function() {}, b: [function() {}] }";
```

to

```
var y = "({a: function() {}, b: [function() {}] })";
```

Or change the call to `eval` to

```
var o = eval('('+y+')');
```

to avoid `eval` thinking you pass a block instead of an object.

Comment: So, if I want to `eval` an rvalue rather than code, I should wrap it in "()"? Is there any downside to that?

Comment: @Domi It has nothing to do with "rvalues", simply about parsing - it is "code" in both cases. When *not* in an Expression context, `{..}` is *not* treated as an Object Literal but rather as a Block Statement. Parenthesis are the easiest (and probably most understood/consistent) way to ensure an Expression context, but not the only way.

Comment: @user2864740 Do you have a link or some more information on this? I'd be interested in alternatives, as well as pros and cons of different "`eval`ing strategies". And FYI: an [rvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)) is a certain kind of expression, the kind of expression I am operating with here.

Comment: @Domi I've added some related questions on the post (see the ["Why the .. bracket.."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360356/why-the-open-quote-and-bracket-for-eval-jsonstring-when-parsing-json?lq=1)). The [ES5 grammar rules](http://es5.github.io/#A) contain the information, but need some reading.